# Get location name in android without internet

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, reverse-geocoding, cellinfo

There are several methods to get location name using lon&lat like GeoCoder or GoogleMap API.

But these methods need to internet for their job!.

is there any way to get location name without internet access?

***note:in some device location name discovered as CellInfo***

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I seriously doubt that it's possible to store a mapping of Lat/Long with the name of the place in an Android device. You need a server to store this amount of data.

But you could create your own database with some location (those you use frequently).

Or just use internet when it's possible (on WIFI only).